# using . instead of / in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I learn laravel and I see that when we extend a view we use '.' instead of '/'

example: @extends('layouts.nav')

my question is why do we use '.' instead of '/' and when I used '/' instead of '.' it did the same work

Comment: The reason for using dots instead of slashes is because Laravel's View class uses dots as namespace separators for views.

Comment: Because you can? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#nested-view-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use dot notation instead of '/'. It's not written in the documents but '/' is used for path separator and in some cases it might return some kind of an error. You can check the laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#nested-view-directories).